# Capture HTTPS traffic from VSTO in fiddler

Tags: fiddler, capture

I am using an Excel VSTO add-in and I want to capture the HTTPS traffic using Fiddler (v4.5.0.0). The add-in downloads data (reports) from the server into the spreadsheet, it has also a pop-up that allows authentication and selection of the elements of the reports.

I am able to capture and decode traffic from all browsers and I have already imported the cert using Internet Options...

I have set Excel's Trust Centre options to the minimum security allowing as much a I could.

Yet when I enable capturing in Excel, no matter if with or without decoding, the addin does not work, and if I enable it after log in using the VSTO's pop-up it shows me a "connection impossible" error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: When Fiddler is running and you navigate IE to the HTTPS url in question, does the browser show any errors?

Comment: Good one. I will check this later. I found a "workaround" but, of course, I would like to avoid spending extra time that I should invest in debugging issues. THX

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is not related to VSTO because there is no difference between a regular .Net application and VSTO add-ins from the Fiddler point of view. Try to reproduce the issue with a regular .net application and Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a (temporary and shabby) workaround:

I try several times enabling and disabling the decrypt option and after a few attempts it works. Note that I had already tried to repeat the request without disabling decryption with no result.

I have also enabled all the SSL and TLS versions supported by Fiddler for good measure.

I will try EmilLaw's suggestion to see what IE says, but for now I am under time pressure as I need to debug a few reports for customers.

Thanks guys for the suggestions!!